# Isn't "orthogonal" antonym to "linear"?

Tags: antonyms

I have a strong feeling that *orthogonal* is an antonym to *linear*. Google didn't show any such citation.

circular motion is counterpart of linear motion. I hope circular motion can be called as orthogonal motion.

Comment: No, circular is definitely not orthogonal. Orthogonal always involves eight angles. Circles involve no angles.

Comment: "Orthogonal" is roughly the antonym of "parallel".

Comment: Orthogonality is orthogonal to linearity

Comment: An antonym to linear is curved.

Comment: *Circular* arguments assume their conclusions. *Orthogonal* arguments are non-sequitors, irrelevant to the topic being debated. They're completely unrelated. Even ... orthogonal concepts.

Comment: Perhaps a near antonym, but would you ever actually use it in that sense?

Comment: @Dan Typing on a phone? I do believe you meant _right_ angles, as opposed to limiting orthogonality to octagons. ;-)

Comment: There are many antonyms to *linear*, depending on the context. I cannot think of any circumstances where *orthogonal* would be one of them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Predictive typing has become sentient and made its sole focus assassinating my character in public. I'm sure of it.

Answer (score 2):

No. At least not in statistics. In fact, the relationship between orthogonal and linear might be orthogonal (i.e.independent).

Two random variables might be linearly independent and orthogonal, just as two variables might be linearly independent but not orthogonal. Similarly, two variables might be linearly dependent and therefore not orthogonal.

[image]

(from [here](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/%7Ebmomen/BIOM621/LineardepCorrOrthogonal.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

In circular motion, the object at any instant of time is making right angle with the centre of the circle. Since orthogonal also means lying/intersecting at a right angle, you could say that circular motion is orthogonal motion. But that doesn't make orthogonal an antonym of linear, even though circular and linear do qualify as antonyms. It is just that the physics of circular motion involves orthogonality.